# Testing AWS Lambda using Jest and Sinon causing Timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs, sinon

I am attempting to execute the following Jest test to test an AWS Lambda locally:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const { handler } = require('../queue_manager.js');

let result = {
    // some result
};

let sinonSandbox;

beforeEach((done) => {
    sinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    done();
})

afterEach((done) => {
    sinonSandbox.restore()
    done();
})

it('queue-manager', async () => {
    sinonSandbox.stub(AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype, 'get').returns({
        promise: function () {
            return Promise.resolve(result);
        }
    });

    const lambdaResponse = { code: 200, data: 'some mocked data' };

    var callback = function() { };
    var context = {}

    const event = {
        somedata: "data"
    };

    const actualValue = await handler(event, context, callback);

    expect(actualValue).toEqual(result);
});
```

I am attempting to test processing after a DynamoDB call, however, the test fails with a: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout

I tried giving it more time but the same result so it is not that it cannot return successfully in 5 seconds, it is not returning all.

Anyone familiar with Sinon that could possibly point out my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Post edited, fist edition pushed at the bottom of the answer a

## Second thought

here is an example on how to test an asynchronous function with Jest

```
test('the data is peanut butter', done => {
  function callback(data) {
    try {
      expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  }

  fetchData(callback);
});
```

then I think the missing part in your code is the `done` callback on the unit test function. could you try this:

```js
it('queue-manager', async (done) => {
    sinonSandbox.stub(AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype, 'get').returns({
        promise: function () {
            return Promise.resolve(result);
        }
    });

    const lambdaResponse = { code: 200, data: 'some mocked data' };

    var callback = function() { };
    var context = {}

    const event = {
        somedata: "data"
    };

    const actualValue = await handler(event, context, callback);

    expect(actualValue).toEqual(result);
    done();
});
```

Another option could be to specify the number of assertions (instead of the callback `done`) :

```js
// before the await handler(...)
expect.assertions(1);
```

Hope this help.

## First lead was the dynamo db ressource hanging:

Quite often the lambda is not returning the result and then runs into timeout because the lambda function is waiting for resources ie: dynamoDB connection for instance.

You can configure the runtime to send the response immediately by setting context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop to false.

First line of the handler must be:

```js
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false
```

Comment: In this case, because the Lambda is running locally, the context object is empty (not running within an AWS environment) so setting callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop does not have any effect on the processing.

Comment: Thank you for the Second Thought suggestions but neither worked in my case. I still suffer from the Timeout issue.